# Does the deprecation of ntext, text, and image affect SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.
>
> Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use **nvarchar(max)**, **varchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** instead.

How does this affect SQL Server Compact Edition? `varbinary(max)` is not currently supported in SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of what a SQL Server Compact expert said, "Microsoft SQL Server != Microsoft SQL Server Compact".

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/29f05956-cb61-48c4-a6f6-c1e2d9fe5ea5

If that changes, I'm sure MSFT will explain when the older types actually get deprecated.